# How can we call batch(bulk) requests using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to call multiple request using ajax but only withing one request and response.

Here scenario is different, I need to cal 'POST' service but in body passing  another 'GET' service call which should run internally and should send the result of total two services.

```
var processJsonContent = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://ServerName/api/batch/",
    contentType:"application/json",
    Type:'POST',
    dataType   : "json",
    data: JSON.stringify([{
      Method:"GET",
      Resource:"https://ServerName/api/getData"
    }]),
    success: function(response) {
      // alert('connected' + JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log('Database Connected' + JSON.stringify(response));
      // var valueURL = response.Items;
      // alert('valueURL' + valueURL);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpqc3dlbEAxMjM=');
    }
  });   
}
```

Please can anyone help to write approach to call bulk of request with one request and response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is, or what you're trying to do

Comment: Do you just want to get multiple contents by one ajax request, or what do you want? Not sure ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of us.

Actually, its simple things.

Download updated rest client(Postman)

-Fill **POST** url, authentication and headers

-Add all **GET** request urls in **BODY** part as **JSON** in **RAW** section

-Once get the result. There is a option **Cookies** and **Code** on postman

### -Click on **Code** option and we can select language and get the code.

**POST Request**-
 https://servername/api/batch/

**Header-** 
 Content-Type- application/json

**Body(raw)**

{

"FistRequest": {

```
            "Method": "GET",

            "Resource": "https://servername/api/getData"

           },
```

"Second Request": {

```
           "Method": "GET",
            "Resource": "https://servername/api/getData1"
           }
```

}

My JQuery code is here-

---

var **settings** = {

"async": true,

"crossDomain": true,

"url": "https://servername/api/batch/",

"method": "POST",

"headers": {

```
"content-type": "application/json",
"authorization": "Basic YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpqc3dlbEAxMjM=",
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"postman-token": "bfff48a9-afa7-8114-e315-799494eb1192"
```

},

---

```
  "processData": false,

  "data": "{

 "FirstRequest": { "Method": "GET","Resource": "https://servername   /api/getData"  }, 

 "Second Request": {"Method": "GET","Resource": "https://servername/api/getData1" } 
            }"

}


$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send GET request after the completion of POST request then you need to declare the GET request in the "Success" function. 
And to get the data from both the requests at the same time, you need to use "return".